Embedding a custom live chat (gen. from Salesforce) into my WordPress header
I'm having trouble embedding a custom live chat (gen. from Salesforce) into my WordPress header. Don't have PRO access. Any suggestions please?

"Don't have PRO access." - you mean the problem is your host (who?) is restricting access, so you can't add custom plugins or edit your theme?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
